# Open source libraries for generating automated summaries

Tags: open-source, nlp

I was looking for a open source library for generating automated summaries out of few words. For ex: if two qualities are given of a person a) good thinking skills b) bad handwriting, i need to generate a sentence like "Bob has good thinking skills however needs to improve on his handwriting". I need to know if any open source library could help me achieve it even partially.

Thanks for help!

-- Mohit

Answer (score 2):

You could start with [MEAD](http://www.summarization.com/mead/).  Not sure what sort of mileage you'll get with single-sentence summarization, but you may be able to do some post-processing on the output and manage it.

Answer (score 1):

It would take a bit of work, but you could also construct something out of [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) and one or more the associated databases (eg. WordNet).  Python, open source.